# how to disable setOnItemSelectedListener(listener) Toast message

Tags: android, message, toast

I have a listener to show a Toast message for when user clicks on a spinner and selects an item.

But when I set the value of the spinner programatically I want to disable the Toast message.
How do i do it.

I have tried setOnItemSelectedListener(null) before programmatically setting the value of spinner then setOnItemSelectedListener(listener) after that 
but the Toast message still shows no matter what i do.

Thanks in advance.

This is all done inside onCreate btw.  I just want to disable the Toast messaging when the onCreate sets default values for the spinner.

here's my listener

```
private OnItemSelectedListener listener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                Weather.TEMP_DESCRIPTION.get(item), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        if (mTemp.getOnItemSelectedListener() != null) {
            toast.show();
        }

    };

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
```

and here's what i have in onCreate()

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            mTemp.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);

            String weather = extras.getString("weather");
            String tempStr = extras.getString("temp_str");
            if (weather.equals(Weather.UNAVAILABLE)) {
                mWeather.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(Weather.ANY_WEATHER));
                if (toast != null) {
                    toast.cancel();
                    toast.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    toast = null;
                }
            } else {
                mWeather.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(weather));
                mTemp.setSelection(tempAdapter.getPosition(tempStr));
                if (toast != null) {
                    toast.cancel();
                    toast.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    toast = null;
                }
            }

        }
mTemp.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

I tried many different things that's why you see all those weird if checks, i tried setting a boolean variable in the class too and it didn't work either.

Comment: can you put your code here??

Comment: yes, i'll do that right now

Comment: sorry but this code is awful .. why don't you just use some object sarray? fx array of `class w2t { string weather; string temp_str; }` or at least why don't you use some kind of dictionary/map class also why are you not getting the selected item inside onitemclick in normal way: `T item  = (T)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` where T is an Adapter's item type ...

Comment: I am a very beginner, and i don't know how to use what you have mentioned yet.

Comment: I'll look into using dictionary/map class right now

Comment: somthing like: static should be fine `static final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();` the feed the map:  `static { map.add(Weather.TEMP_EXTREME_COLD, "below -10°"); map.add(Weather.TEMP_COLD, "below 0°"); ... }` then use it(without ifs): `String   item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position); String toast = item + ": " map.get(item);`

Comment: yeah i am slowly working that into my code right now thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Global boolean:**

```
public boolean userSet = true;
```

**On Create:**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        userSet = false;
        mTemp.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);

        String weather = extras.getString("weather");
        String tempStr = extras.getString("temp_str");
        if (weather.equals(Weather.UNAVAILABLE)) {
            mWeather.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(Weather.ANY_WEATHER));
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
                toast.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                toast = null;
            }
        } else {
            mWeather.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(weather));
            mTemp.setSelection(tempAdapter.getPosition(tempStr));
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
                toast.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                toast = null;
            }
        }

        mTemp.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
    }
```

**Listener:**

```
private OnItemSelectedListener listener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

       if (!userSet) {
           userSet = true;
           return;
       }
 }
```

Comment: I have struggled this for long.  Thanks you're the man, exiting early is genius.

Comment: I also deleted a lot of code with this change, all the if checks toast is null and I don't have to worry about setting the setOnItemSelectedListener(null).

Answer (score 0):

You can call cancel() in the moment you set the value of the spinner programmatically to cancel the toast.

Comment: I tried .cancel() setting Visibility(View.INVISIBLE) and setting the toast object to null as well but nothing seems to work, if toast.show() is called it will always show, and cancel() seems to have no effect after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

and when you need to show toast you use toast.show();

when you need to hide you use
toast.cancel(); or dismiss or hide dont remember...

Answer (score 0):

Spinners are tricky..Even when you programmatically set the value of a spinner, the onItemSelected will get called no matter what. So in onCreate, just set the value as you want and then call SetOnItemSelected.

Inside onItemSelected, you have to handle this case separately. You can use a flag, if flag is set, do nothing, else display toast. A counter can be used as well. Initiate the counter = 0; then use the following piece of code

```
  {
  if (spinner_count == 0)
  {
     spinner_count++;
  }
  else
  {
     //Display Toast message or whatever you want to do. 
  }
```

But this approach has a challenge. If the user selects what you have set programmatically, onItemSelected will not get called since android will not identify it as a change. In that case, you can decide to have a Submit button to supplement this. Or you can add another fake entry to your list of items in the spinner dropdown and set that as default option programmatically.